# Recursion without executing all methods on each recursive call

Tags: recursion

What's the term for when a recursive algorithm doesn't always reach all functions on each level? Consider this code:

```
function f(value):
    if val < -10 return g(value + 1)
    if var > 10 return h(value - 1)
    else return 0

function g(value):
    if value % 2 == 0 return f(value / 2)
    else return h(value)

function h(value):
    if value % 2 == 1 return g(value - 1)
    else return h(value - 1)
```

Each recursive call may call a different function such as when we start with `15`:

```
f(15)
  h(14)
    h(13)
      g(12)
        f(6)
          return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of a specific term for what you describe, it's simply referred to as recursion.

The fact that it executes potentially different pathways for certain levels of recursion doesn't really make it special, any more than the same feature in a loop:

```
for i = 1 to 10:
    if i is even:
        print i, " is even"
    else:
        print i, " is odd"
```

That's still called a loop (not something like "alternating loop" or "iteration dependent behavioural loop"). It's similar to your recursion example.

In fact, recursion *always* has different behaviour at at least one level (the last one) since, without that, it would recur forever and you would most likely overflow the stack.